# Subprocess File Operations in Python

Tags: python, command-line, automation, subprocess

I have a command line program which can be run through the following subprocess.

```
subprocess.call([CMD.bat, '-infile', infile1.tif, infile2.tif, '-outfile', outfile.tif])
```

When input files are a few, there is no problem with the above code.

However, when the input files are many, it becomes difficult to input them all. So, I wanted to use glob.glob to input all files.

```
files = glob.glob("D:\\*.tif")

files = ",".join(files)

subprocess.call([CMD.bat, '-infile', files, '-outfile', outfile.tif])
```

Unluckily, this code does not run at all.
How to solve this problem?

Any ideas, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't put that `files` in as a single argument, you need to unpack it:

```
files = glob.glob("D:\\*.tif")
subprocess.call(['cmd.bat', '-infile', *files, '-outfile', 'outfile.tif'])
```

Notice the `*` used for unpacking arguments. For more info on unpacking, see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)

No need to `join` the arguments first, that just creates a long string (that is still one single argument)

An example:

```
files = ['1.tif', '2.tif']
cmd = ['cmd.bat', '-infile', *files, '-outfile', 'outfile.tif']
print(cmd) # ['cmd.bat', '-infile', '1.tif', '2.tif', '-outfile', 'outfile.tif']
```

Comment: It worked like charm. Would be grateful if you  explain more about the heck of `*`.

Comment: @mk1 I edited in a link with some additional explanation and examples